# Wordpress menu switcher

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a plugin or at least an idea on how to make a menu switcher in Wordpress with a select in HTML. I have two menus or more and when I select an option I need it to be changed. I googled a lot but I didn't found any answers or plugin for that. Can you guys help me with some suggestions.

Update:

HTML:

```html
<form action='' method='post'>
  <select name='menu_select' onchange="this.form.submit();">
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Alege meniu</option>
    <option value='meniu_1'>Meniu 1</option>
    <option value='meniu_2'>Meniu 2</option>
    <option value='meniu_3'>Meniu 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

One of the PHP conditions:

```html
if(isset($_POST['menu_select']) && $_POST['menu_select'] == 'meniu_1'){
    $_SESSION['menu_select'] = $_POST['menu_select'];
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary_menu', 
         'container' => '',
         'menu_class' => 'menu',
         'walker' => new menu_walker()
          ) );
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can create two header or create two menu..you can get key with help of session

Comment: I created the menus, but I don't know how to use sessions to keep the selected menu when I go to another page.

Comment: make sure you add session_start() before get_header() ; :)

Comment: It's at top of the file. Before <!doctype html>.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code. Maybe will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first set session and then get session value.after get value just put if else condition.

**Step 1** 
First set session as follow:(put code in **function.php**)

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

**Step 2** Get session value (if user set second value then if part execute )

**Note that session is set**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['menu_select'])){
$get_val = $_REQUEST['menu_select'];
if($get_val =='meniu_1'){$_SESSION['menu']='meniu_1';}
elseif($get_val =='meniu_2'){$_SESSION['menu']='meniu_2';}
elseif($get_val =='meniu_3'){$_SESSION['menu']='meniu_3';}
else{$_SESSION['menu']='default';}
}
if($_SESSION['menu']=="meniu_1"){
//You compare value in condition
//MENU 1 CODE
}elseif($_SESSION['menu']=="meniu_2"){
//MENU 2 CODE
}elseif($_SESSION['menu']=="meniu_3")
{
//MENU 3 CODE
}else{

//MENU default CODE
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I did exactly what you said above.

Comment: have you set session value to execute else part  ?

Comment: Yes. But I have more than two menus. I have the original one set and three more in the select dropdown. I did a var_dump and I get this depending on what I select: array(1) { ["menu_select"]=> string(7) "meniu_2" }. But when I refresh the page the original menu is shown.

Comment: try  to use else if and check your session when page refresh

Comment: The var_dump I said above was with $_SESSION, the result is in my last comment.

Comment: You asked me if I check the value in session on page refresh.

Comment: when user want to change menu ..just make on click page refresh and set session  :)

Comment: The refresh is ok when submited the select option. The session looks ok too. But when I refresh  the page again the menu is not staying. It show the first main menu. I want the menu to stay as I choosed when I go to another page. Sorry for asking too much...Can you give me an example on what you mean.

Comment: I header.php where I display the menu.

Comment: put session_start() in first line of header.php

Comment: please print your session value after session_start()

Comment: Ok. I did a var_dump($_SESSION) and first result is array(1) { ["menu_select"]=> NULL }. When I select a menu from the list I get array(1) { ["menu_select"]=> string(7) "meniu_1" }

Comment: you can use print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: Why do that when it's almost the same thing with var_dump.

Comment: your session is not set when user click

Comment: How do you know that? How can I set it then? I did exactly what you said on those two steps.

Comment: have you create a from to get value?

Comment: If you mean a form, I already posted it on my question. So the answer would be yes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `onSelect` option which will send a get parameter, get this parament in `header.php` according to this

show the menu

Comment: I want something similar with what's here https://www.slsp.sk/sk/ludia on header. I only want my menu to change not the whole page. How do I get the menus, that is what I don't know. For example: I have a select from where i can select pages by ids. I want to do something like this for menus.